# Remove line from shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I need to remove line from shape, but when I use pathfinder tool, it makes shape from my line(Arc tool), then removes it.

How to remove only line itself?

These are my lines, I want them to cut through the circle:

[image: Lines should be removed, so when exporting to png, they be transparent!]

This is what happens when I use pathfinder and delete the shapes, (it adds in extra space)

[image: Remove only line]

Comment: Can you provide a more elaborate image of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: done! Green lines should be removed. They were created using Arc tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to select all the lines and Expand them.

Go to **Object → Expand**, you only need to select Stroke.

[image]

This will convert your strokes to paths (fixing that mistake which is caused by the computer auto selecting an area to fill)

Then you can use the *Pathfinder* (**Window → Pathfinder** or <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) to cut them through.

---

You can also do **Object → Path → Outline Stroke** which does the same thing (in your scenario)

Comment: Expand - new tool I learned right now! Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

A nondestructive method (that's not much because you can allways have a copy of the curves):

[image]

The magenta shape is only to show the transparency

1. Group your curves
2. Make the curves white
3. Select the curves and the black circle. From the top right menu of the Transparency panel select Make Opacity Mask, no clip, invert

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the shape builder tool. 
Select the whole shape.
Click on the shape builder tool.
While pressing the alt key drag the mouse cursor along the line you want to remove

Comment: +1 I like the shape builder tool. Sidenote: For some reason Adobe is trying to get you to not use it in the newer CC releases and annoyingly advises you to try their new tool which I don't really like.